# Intercept and modify file system call - Windows

Tags: .net, windows, file, system, minifilter

Short Version:  Is there a way to 'intercept' a Windows (XP or 7) file system call to open a file and replace said call with a different file name?

Long Version:  I am trying to help a customer recover from a HDD corruption.  The computer in question is in a kiosk that simply plays two Flash files in combination with a webcam.  It is controlled by a compiled .exe from MDM Zinc.  I have the two Flash files and a copy of the .exe.

The problem is, only one of the Flash files opens.  After MUCH head banging, I finally watched what is happening through Systernals Process Monitor.  Both of the .flv files are in the same folder.  I can see very clearly in Process Mon that the .exe calls the working one as c:\somedirectory\anotherdirectory\file1.flv.  The non-working one though APPARENTLY has a typo in that it has two backslashes side-by-side in the path:  c:\somedirectory\ \anotherdirectory\file2.flv

I am told that this is the only version of the .exe that is available and that the company who created it is out of business, so what I have is all I am going to get.  If it is indeed a typo, I can't imagine how it ever could have worked.  I have to think that there was a different version out there.  Of course, if it really is a typo in the .exe, the worst possible character that it could have been was another \ since that is invalid in a directory or file name and I can't simply move the file in question to a new path.  (found today that you can actually create a directory in Windows with a seemingly blank name (ALT-255) but that was a long shot which didn't work).

My programming skills are not incredibly strong, but researching today sort of lead me to think that minifilter or API hooking *might* be an answer?  I've tried decompiling the .exe as well as popping it open in a HEX editor and unfortunately, the path in question does not appear to be a string that is readily available for editing.  If either of those are a valid option, I would really appreciate a (hard) push in the right direction.  If you can think of anything else that I might try, I'm pretty much out of ideas.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the [EasyHook](http://easyhook.codeplex.com/) library to accomplish this. The article about EasyHook at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27637/EasyHook-The-reinvention-of-Windows-API-hooking specifically contains an example for how to override `CreateFile`, the method that the .NET framework uses to open a file.

Comment: Thank you!  On the surface, that looks very promising...  I am about to read through it more carefully now.

Comment: Open up the exe and find that path.
Then change it to match what you want and save.

Comment: I just ran up some test code with fopen_s(...); and CreateFile
"\\\\" in a path doesn't break either call.
You may be looking for a different problem...